# Was this the right way to make a closure for my purpose?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I'm slowly understanding closures more and more, and the following code works. I'm wondering if there is a simpler/better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here.

In the code below, `this` refers simply to an object, which has a `sections` property that is an array. I loop over this array, and bind to hover event of each `el` property (a DOM element) of each `section`. The callback I supply to the `hover()` method is where the closure comes in. The main `this` object has two methods `.sectionMouseenter()` and `.sectionMouseleave()` that get called depending on whether the event type (represented by `e.type` in my code) is `mouseenter` or `mouseleave`. As an argument, the current section is passed to these methods. Of course, an iteration of a `for` loop has no variable scope in JavaScript, so a closure is necessary to encapsulate the reference of the `section` variable.

```
    for (var i = this.sections.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var section = that.sections[i];
        section.el.hover(
            (function(section){
                return function(e){
                    that['section' + e.type.capitalize()](section);
                }
            })(section)
        );
    };
```

Is this the "correct" way to have written this closure, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't construct the function on the fly, but put it outside the for-loop.

```
var sections = this.sections;

function dummy(section) {
    return function(e) {
        that['section' + e.type.capitalize()](section);
    }
}

for (var i = sections.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    section.el.hover( dummy(sections[i]) );
}
```

Comment: That is really good advice. And Max you will find it really simplifies your logic.

Comment: +1. Thanks, this is exactly why I asked this question. I'm going to leave it open for a little while to see what other responses might come in.

Comment: +1 very readable, no reason to re-declare the function every time you loop if the function is static.